# I can't figure out why my python script works but when try to make it an executable it does not work

Tags: python, pyinstaller, executable, barcode-printing

I'm having an issue with running a script as an executable. I believe it has to do with MEIXXXXX but am not sure how to remedy it. The script below runs perfectly when run in python 3.10.5 but when I create an executable the file won't save or create.

```
import os
from tkinter import Button, Entry, Label, Tk

import barcode
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter

root = Tk()
root.minsize(400, 200)

# Add Title from Filename

title = os.path.basename(__file__)[0:-3]
root.title(title.title())

# Get the path of the running file

fp = os.path.dirname(__file__)
os.chdir(fp)


def calculated(event=None):
    # Define content of the barcode as a string
    # Get entry as an input for the barcode 11 char or 12 if you know the checksum digit.
    number = e1.get()
    # calulate the checksum and store the full barcode in the variable 'cs'
    cs = barcode.UPCA(number).get_fullcode()
    # print(cs)
    # Get the required barcode format
    barcode_format = barcode.get_barcode_class("upc")

    # Generate barcode and render as image
    my_barcode = barcode_format(number, writer=ImageWriter())

    # Save barcode as PNG

    my_barcode.save(cs)


lbl1 = Label(root, text="Enter UPC-A code : ")
lbl1.grid(column=0, row=0)
e1 = Entry(root)
e1.grid(column=1, row=0, ipadx=5, padx=5, pady=5)
btn1 = Button(root, text="Calculate", command=calculated)
btn1.grid(column=2, row=0)
root.bind('<Return>', calculated)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I got it to work.... are you using windows os?\

Comment: Perhaps my system settings won't allow for the saving of files. I'll try it on a laptop or non network system. It does run from Python shell but not once it is an exe file.

Comment: I use Windows 10 Pro and Python 3.10.5 as individual user. Not all users. Maybe that could be the issue?

Comment: Ill post a step by step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the steps I took to make it work.

1. `mkdir newdir` and `cd newdir`
2. `py -m venv venv` and `venv\Scripts\activate`
3. `py -m pip install --upgrade pip pyinstaller pillow python-barcode`
4. `touch main.py`

**main.py**

```
import os
from tkinter import Button, Entry, Label, Tk
import barcode
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter

root = Tk()
root.minsize(400, 200)

# Add Title from Filename

title = os.path.basename(__file__)[0:-3]
root.title(title.title())


def calculated(event=None):
    # Define content of the barcode as a string
    # Get entry as an input for the barcode 11 char or 12 if you know the checksum digit.
    number = e1.get()
    # calulate the checksum and store the full barcode in the variable 'cs'
    cs = barcode.UPCA(number).get_fullcode()
    # print(cs)
    # Get the required barcode format
    barcode_format = barcode.get_barcode_class("upc")

    # Generate barcode and render as image
    my_barcode = barcode_format(number, writer=ImageWriter())

    # Save barcode as PNG
    path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),cs)  # <--- added this
    my_barcode.save(path)


lbl1 = Label(root, text="Enter UPC-A code : ")
lbl1.grid(column=0, row=0)
e1 = Entry(root)
e1.grid(column=1, row=0, ipadx=5, padx=5, pady=5)
btn1 = Button(root, text="Calculate", command=calculated)
btn1.grid(column=2, row=0)
root.bind('<Return>', calculated)
root.mainloop()
```

I made some very minor alterations to make sure the images were written to the users current directory instead of writing them to the temporary runtime folder.

5. `pyinstaller -F main.py`
6. inside `main.spec` add a tuple containing the path to the barcode fonts folder and the target path for app runtime.

**main.spec**

```
a = Analysis(
    ['main.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[('./venv/Lib/site-packages/barcode/fonts', './barcode/fonts')], # add this
    ...
```

7. `pyinstaller main.spec`
8. `dist\main.exe`

And that's it.

Comment: I found your answer helpful in more ways than one. I almost never used virtual environment. I always cleared out my site directory and made a fresh setup.  Why is the font library in the virtual environment site packages added to the datas. Is it because only the *.py files are copied?

Comment: @MichaelMulvey  You should always use a virtual enviornment when using pyinstaller... otherwise pyinstaller has a tendency to include librarys in the executable that you don't actually need and ends up inflating the size of the file.  And for some reason pyinstaller doesn't add the fonts folder automatically.